# Showing name of user on a different page

Tags: winforms

I'm still learn about windows forms and on my form1 I have the user control.
But on my form3 I wanna show something like Hi User… and on my sql table I have de "username", "password", and the "name" of person that's log in but i don't know how!

Extract of the login code:

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter($"Select Count(*) from [Table] Where username = '{textBox1.Text}' and password ='{textBox2.Text}'", selectConnection: con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);

        if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
        {

            this.Hide();

            Form2 ss = new Form2();
            ss.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Username or password incorrect, try again!.", "Alert", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);    
        }
```

If someone can help me I realy appreciate and sorry about my English.

Answer (score 0):

Just to remember there is Stack Overflow in portuguese: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/

Anyway hope this can help you out.

1. I will change all logic at the end of this explanation, but just to make more easy to understand some points one by one. So , first make the SQL connecion into using blocks, something like this: ( doing so , you don´t need to manually close the connection and to dispose the objects..)

   ```
   using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
   {
        using(SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter($"Select Count(*) from [Table] Where username = '{textBox1.Text}' and password ='{textBox2.Text}'", selectConnection: con))
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
        }
   }
   ```
2. To avoid SQL Injection parametized your query with something like:

   ```
   using(SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter($"Select Count(*) from [Table] Where username =@username and password =@username, selectConnection: con))

      SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter();
      parameter.ParameterName = "@username";
      parameter.Value = "xyz";
      // code: same to the password.....
   ```
3. Make your SQL connection logic anyway out of your ButtonClick event. Make a method for it so you just need to call it;
4. As a said at my first explanation let´s make it more readable, so please do this:

   ```
     using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
     {
         conn.Open();

         using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select Count(*) from [yourTable] Where username=@username and password=@username", conn))
         {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username","theusername");
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password","thepassword");
             // int result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (reader.Read())
                {
                   MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Hi {0}",reader["username"]));
                }
            }
         }
     }
   ```